# Dart, is it possible to create an instance with the default constructor without mirrors?

Tags: constructor, dart, dart-mirrors

I'm trying to cut down on my dart2js output by utilising @MirrorsUsed, though I currently have to register more types than I would like to as I need it to know that certain classes have a default constructor as I do something like this:

```
var a = reflectClass(A).newInstance(const Symbol(''), new List<dynamic>()).reflectee;
```

but if I haven't registered `class A` with @MirrorsUsed it fails to create an instance of A because it doesn't know whether it has a default constructor given by `const Symbol('')`.

Is there anyway in dart for creating an instance of a Type just from the Type without having to reflect on it asI have done above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the types in advance you could create a factory and avoid mirrors entirely. This way you have to hardcode the instantiation though but might be less maintenance work as applying MirrorsUsed.

Comment: you are right, this will be better than my current mirrors method, thanks.

Comment: I'm still wrapping my wits around Dart. But, since you already have A (as given as the parameter to reflectClass), why not instantiate it in the usual manner?

Comment: In Dart you currently can't call a constructor on a type passed as argument. There is a proposal to implement meta classes to support that.